# PyMySQL refusing to install on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, mysql, raspberry-pi, phpmyadmin

I have tried every answer I can find to install PyMySQL for example see below:

```
sudo pip install PyMySQL
Downloading/unpacking PyMySQL
Downloading PyMySQL-0.7.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl (78kB): 78kB downloaded
Installing collected packages: PyMySQL
Successfully installed PyMySQL
```

But still no luck, it just returns the following when .py script is run which uses pymysql:

```
python UpworkCode.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "UpworkCode.py", line 2, in <module>
import PyMySQL
ImportError: No module named PyMySQL
```

Please could someone help me out of this pit of despair thanks

EDIT:

Tried using: `sudo apt-get install python3-pymysql`

But still produced this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3-pymysql
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing python3? 
this has been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33446347/no-module-named-pymysql but the answer is a bit old so it may not apply any longer.

Comment: Hey Jesse, I just tried to follow their steps but it produces an error:

Comment: sudo apt-get install python3-pymysql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3-pymysql

Comment: Use apt-cache search. Maybe it is named differently. ` apt-cache search python | grep mysql` and see what you got.